# DraftJS: how to move the focus (cursor) to some character on the right, programmatically?

Tags: javascript, draftjs

I am inserting some text in the editor using this:

```
_insertText(text) {
    const { editorState, onChange } = this.props
    const newContentState = Modifier.insertText(
      editorState.getCurrentContent(),
      editorState.getSelection(),
      text
    )

    const newState = EditorState.createWithContent(newContentState)
    onChange(EditorState.acceptSelection(newState, editorState.getSelection()))
  }
```

But after the insertion, the cursor stay at the anchor position, at the insertion point. I would like to move it to the end of the inserted text, so I can continue editing without having to move the cursor manually.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed with this

```
_insertText(text) {
    const { editorState, onChange } = this.props
    const newContentState = Modifier.insertText(
      editorState.getCurrentContent(),
      editorState.getSelection(),
      text
    )

    const newState = EditorState.createWithContent(newContentState)
    const nextOffSet = editorState.getSelection().getFocusOffset() + text.length

    const newSelection = editorState.getSelection().merge({
      focusOffset: nextOffSet,
      anchorOffset: nextOffSet
    })

    onChange(EditorState.acceptSelection(newState, newSelection))
  }
```

If there is a better solution, please let me know.